# 'str' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python

i want to return sequence, id and symbol line in a file like this :

```
CLUSTAL O(1.2.4) multiple sequence alignment


P04637-2      ---PQSDPSVEPPLSQETFSD-WKLLPENNVLSPLPSQAMDDLMLSPDDIEQWFTEDPGP
P04637-3      MEEPQSDPSVEPPLSQETFSDLWKLLPENNVLSPLPSQAMDDLMLSPDDIEQWFTEDPGP
                 ****************** **************************************

P04637-2      DEAPRMPEAAPPVAPAPAAPTPAAPAPAPSWPLSSSVPSQKTYQGSYGFRLGFLHSGTAK
P04637-3      DEAPRMPEAAPPVAPAPAAPTPAAPAPAPSWPLSSS-PSQKTYQGSYGFRLGFLHSGTAK
              ************************************ ***********************

P04637-2      SVTCTYSPALNKMFCQLAKTCPVQLWVDSTPPPGTRVRAMAIYKQSQHMTEVVRRCPHHE
P04637-3      SVTCTYSPALNKMFCQLAKTCPVQLWVDSTPPPGTRVRAMAIYKQSQHMTEVVRRCPHHE
              ************************************************************
```

i use for this : regular expression but i've got some issue in the code...
i think the problem comes to the .group()
terminal :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "recup_early.py", line 75, in <module>
    Openfile(sys.argv[1])
  File "recup_early.py", line 42, in Openfile
    print(line.group(3))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'group'
```

code :

```
 import re
 import os
 import sys


def Openfile(name_file) :
#determination of the pattern of id and seq line 
    pattern_id_seq = "(\S*)(\s*)(\S*)\n"

    

#determination of the pattern of symbol line 
        #pattern_symbol = ".(**)"

#compilation of the pattern 
    regular_expre_id_and_seq = re.compile(pattern_id_seq)

#determination of the pattern of symbol line 
#regular_expre_symbol_line = re.compile() #a determiner

    id_ref = ''
    id_iso = ''
    liste_aa_ref = ''
    liste_aa_iso = ''
    liste_symbol = ''

#boolean to said :' ok it s the line for ref or it s a line for iso '
    next_line_iso = 0

#open file 
    with open(name_file) as f :
    #read line 
        lines = f.readlines()

    #read line per line
        for line in lines :

        #case of line is a ref line 
            if next_line_iso == 0 :

            #search the ref pattern == true 
                if re.search(regular_expre_id_and_seq,line) :
                #add seq ref in v id_ref
                    print(line.group(3))
                    liste_aa_ref += line.group(3)
                    next_line_iso = 1
            #case of id ref is empty
                    if id_ref == '' :
                #add id ref 
                        id_ref = regular_expre_id_and_seq.group(1)
            
    #case of line is a iso line 
            if next_line_iso == 1 :

        #search the ref pattern == true 
                if re.search(regular_expre_id_and_seq,line) :
                #add seq iso in v id_iso
                    liste_aa_iso += regular_expre_id_and_seq.group(3)
                    next_line_iso = 0
                #case of id iso is empty
                    if id_iso == '' :
                        #add id iso
                        id_iso = regular_expre_id_and_seq.group(1)

        # if re.search(regular_expre_symbol_line) :
        # liste_symbol += regular_expre_id_and_seq.group(2)

#test the programme 
    print("id_ref =", id_ref) 
    print("id_iso =", id_iso)
    print("liste_aa_ref =", liste_aa_ref)
    print("liste_aa_iso =", liste_aa_iso)
    print("liste_symbol =", liste_symbol)


#call the first fonction with in (par) a file 

Openfile(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mre].

Comment: `group` is an attribute of the return value from `re.search()` (and several other `re` functions), which you're currently just throwing away.

Comment: As @jasonharper points out, you are not saving the results of your `re.search()`. `line` is a string as it comes from your `for` loop: `for line in lines`.

Comment: I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group()` is a method of the result of `re.search()`. You need to save that result in a variable, then use the method there.

So change

```
                if re.search(regular_expre_id_and_seq,line) :
                #add seq ref in v id_ref
                    print(line.group(3))
                    liste_aa_ref += line.group(3)
                    next_line_iso = 1
```

to

```
                result = re.search(regular_expre_id_and_seq,line)
                if result:
                #add seq ref in v id_ref
                    print(result.group(3))
                    liste_aa_ref += result.group(3)
                    next_line_iso = 1
```

You have a similar problem after `if re.search(regular_expre_id_and_seq,line):` which should be fixed the same way.